# jquery Ajax statusCode behaving unexpectedly

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
  $.get('/users/test/' + username, {
    statusCode: {
      409: () => {
        valid = false;
        alert(username + ' is unavailable');
      },
      200: () => {
        valid = true;
      }
    }
  });
```

On my server I should see:

`"GET /users/test/asdf HTTP/1.0" 200 0`

But instead I see jquery taking the pleasure of appending some stupid query string:

`"GET /users/test/asdf?statusCode%5B200%5D=&statusCode%5B409%5D= HTTP/1.0" 200 0`

Jquery is getting back a 200 but the 409 code still runs. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass an object in the second argument containing what looks like what are intended to be status code based response handlers.

jQuery doesn't do that that way. The second argument of [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) is the optional `data` argument which is used to pass data to the server. jQuery serializes this data and includes it as the query string in the `get` request.

---

You probably wanted to use the other form of that function which accepts a configuration object that includes the url:

```
$.get({
    url: '/users/test/' + username, 
    statusCode: {
      409: () => {
        valid = false;
        alert(username + ' is unavailable');
      },
      200: () => {
        valid = true;
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: So what does this mean: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-settings ? Obviously it doesn't seem to be working when I tried it, but is it supposed to work if I pass in an object as the only parameter?.

Comment: @DavidTan That's a different invocation that only takes a configuration object. By including the url as an argument rather than as part of the configuration object, you told jQeury to use a different invocation than you intended. I've updated my answer to take this into account.

Comment: Well I'll be damned... that's actually the first thing I tried, but it wasn't working at all so I tried moving the URL outside the object and it seemed to partially work. I must've had a typo or something in my first attempt. Thanks for the help.